# Can we track currently active sessions in Python Flask

Tags: python, session, flask

In my Flask Web-app, a new *session* is created whenever a new user logs in.
At the server-end, is there a way to track the currently *active sessions*?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Flask-Login for your user session management then `is_authenticated` property of Flask-login tells you if the user is logged in or not:

```
if not current_user.is_authenticated:
    return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
```

If you want to protect your views you can use `@login_required` decorator. By default, when a user attempts to access a login_required view without being logged in, Flask-Login will flash a message and redirect them to the login view. (If the login view is not set, it will abort with a 401 error.)

```
@app.route("/settings")
@login_required
def settings():
    pass
```

See the [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_required)

Comment: this I have already done, **thanks**.  
What I was looking for is more like being able to identify the number of sessions that have been created:  
  - what are the users logged in for each of the sessions etc.  
basically more of a top-level perspective of the currently active/serviced sessions.